# Displaying html links in a different order on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a bunch of static links currently within a div, however Im after changing the order of the links on page load.

I've considered using a literal and a loop through the links in code behind but im stumped. Maybe a repeater... I need a push in the right direction please!

Im fairly new to this so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

(c# or vb.Net)

Comment: Question the static links..? do you know the names or id's of the divs where you could possibly get the div tags and store them in a List<T> or SortedList perhaps.. not sure exactly how you are initially reading the liks .. can you provide more information

Comment: Yeah I know the div IDs. The links dont need to be in the markup I could create a  List<T> in code behind and populate it with the links if this can be done. Im currentlynot reading the links, they are just hardcoded in the markup

Comment: Here is a better option as well can you store the links in the .config file or some extraneous .txt file and load the links into the List<T> that way you can load from a text file using Generics in one line of code.. I will post an example below if you like

Comment: Ah ok sounds like a good idea. Yes please an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a quick and easy way to load a file plus you don't have to worry about all that FileStream creation and reading individually each line.. let me know if you need anything else or how this solution works out for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so lets say that you would store the links in a Links.txt file because there could be hundreds of links for example..

```
1. Create the .txt file
2. Make note of the file location.
3. Save the file with the links in them
4. use this code in your project to load the links 

List<string> strUrlLinks = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(FilePath + FileName.txt));
```

in code you can then hover over strUrlLinks and you will see the Links
to access the individual links do it based on it's [Index] position

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for an answer in c# or vb.net and may have some technical restraints on this, but to create this functionality in jQuery is almost trivial considering the links are already hardcoded on the page.

See the example below which sorts in descending order on the link text.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="linksContainer">    
<a href="page1.asp" class="1">Line 1</a>
<a href="page3.asp" class="3">Line 3</a>
<a href="page2.asp" class="2">Line 2</a>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
var orderDivLinks = function(desc) {
    $('div#linksContainer').children().detach().sort(function(a,b) {
           var compA = $(a).text();
           var compB = $(b).text();
           return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(document.body);
}
orderDivLinks(0);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```